# How to recursively iterate through a recursive data structure

Tags: java, recursion

I have a datastructure as follows:

```
 public class A{
    String number;
    Map <String ,B> BMap;
 }

 public class B{
    String number;
    Map <String ,A> AMap;
 }
```

---

```
0 B
    0.0 A
    0.1 A
        0.1.0 B
         ...so on
     1 B
      1.0 A
         1.0.0 B
    1.1 A
```

and so on. **Note:** No `B` comes after `B`.

Now i want to iterate though the map of class `B`, i.e `AMap`. I am trying to create an XML-structure out of it. I want some attribute like id-number. The id-number at each level for `A` and `B` should be like we have structure in books. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why the circular references (`A->B->A->...`) ? Why not simply do: `public class A {
    String number;
    Map <String, A> map;
 }`?

Answer (score 1):

look at the problem as a [bipartite-graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), and run a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

EDIT: added code snap

I did not debug it, but it should be something like that [look at the iterate method]. Activate it with `iterate(new HashSet<A>(),new HashSet<B>())`

```
public class A{
    String number;
    Map<String ,B> BMap;
    public void iterate(Set<A> aVisited,Set<B> bVisited) {
        for (Entry<String, B> entry : BMap.entrySet()) {
            if (bVisited.contains(entry.getValue())) continue;
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            bVisited.add(entry.getValue());
            entry.getValue().iterate(aVisited,bVisited);
        }
    }

}

public class B{
    String number;
    Map<String ,A> AMap;
    public void iterate(Set<A> aVisited,Set<B> bVisited) {
        for (Entry<String, A> entry : AMap.entrySet()) {
            if (aVisited.contains(entry.getValue())) continue;
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            aVisited.add(entry.getValue());
            entry.getValue().iterate(aVisited,bVisited);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @saurabh ranu: I added a code snap, I did not debug it, but it should be the general approach.

Comment: well I don't see you created any xml structure a.What i can see u r just visiting ..i need a xml structure out of it with id numbers as the xml structure i have displaced above..

Comment: @saurabh ranu: you can add a `List<Object>` indicating the so far hirerchy to the parameters. My answer aimed only to give a possible direction on how to approach this problem

Comment: tis is completely different from what i asked...u just copied from somewhere and pasted here....